# Determining Point Coordinates From a Given Vector Field

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I seem to have gotten stuck on exactly what to do for this problem. Below is the question, plus my guess right under

[image: Here's the question, plus my guess right under it.]

I decided to take the partial of the first point (with respect to x) and then take the second partial with respect to y, but now I'm stuck. Is this question even asking for partials? Could I grab a hint about what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The square of the wind speed is

$$\Vert F\Vert^2=\frac{x^2+y^2}{e^{2(x^2+y^2-1)^2}}$$

This is function of $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

Try to find the maximum of it in regards with $r$. This avoids using $x,y$ coordinates and partial derivatives.

Comment: Are you suggesting I substitute $x^2 + y^2$ with $r^2$? That's my one plan I see in this

Comment: @CurlyFry Yes. This is my suggestion. You can even substitute $x^2+y^2$ with a variable $u \ge 0$ in order to simplify further. Interesting that you justify why using the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

I find that, upon differentiating wrt $r$, the critical points are $r=0$ and $r=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}2}$.

But $r=0$ gives speed $0$.

So I suppose we take $r=\sqrt{\dfrac12 +\dfrac{\sqrt2}2}$ as the only possibility.